# Netty https ( TLS ) Session duration: why is renegotiation needed?

Tags: session, scala, https, ssl, netty

I have a 100% https web server that does TLS renegotiation. This is very useful so that users can come to the site and get some nice pages before clicking the login button and being asked for their client certificate. Below is the part of the code that does renegotiation [line 213-236 of X509Cert class](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/read-write-web/file/b920b4d63786/src/main/scala/auth/X509Cert.scala#l213)

```scala
import org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler

val sslh = r.underlying.context.getPipeline.get(classOf[SslHandler])

trySome(sslh.getEngine.getSession.getPeerCertificates.toIndexedSeq) orElse {
  if (!fetch) None
  else {
    sslh.setEnableRenegotiation(true) // todo: does this have to be done on every request?
    r match {
      case UserAgent(agent) if needAuth(agent) => sslh.getEngine.setNeedClientAuth(true)
      case _ => sslh.getEngine.setWantClientAuth(true)
    }
    val future = sslh.handshake()
    future.await(30000) //that's certainly way too long.
    if (future.isDone && future.isSuccess)
      trySome(sslh.getEngine.getSession.getPeerCertificates.toIndexedSeq)
    else
      None
  }
}
```

Now I was expecting that once someone authenticates with an X509 Client certificate the  session would last a little while and remember that certificate chain - say 10 minutes or more, and in any case at the very least 1 minute.  Indeed that is why I have the option of calling the above method with the variable "fetch" set to false. I am hoping that if someone authenticated the connection does not need to be renegotiated.

But I noticed on my  that with most browsers it looks like I need to call sslh.handshake() every time if I want to get the session and return the X509 Certificates. If "fetch" is set to false, then I mostly get returned None.

Is this normal, or is there something I am doing wrong?

PS.

- the code above is part of an implementation of the [WebID protocol](http://webid.info/spec)
- This is using netty 3.2.5Final. I also tried with 3.2.7Final without more luck.
- So I had to change the code of the [current service running the above code](https://foafssl.org/srv/idp?rs=http://bblfish.net/) so that it always forces a handshake (see [the  commit](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/read-write-web/rev/fc3c5c54f72b)) But this does not give me as much flexibility as I hoped to have.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out I was having a problem with unfiltered's use of netty. I found this when implementing the same on Play 2.0.

See [bug report 215 on Play2.0](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401-play-20/tickets/215-tls-https-support-in-play-20#ticket-215-3), and on unfiltered [bug 111: secure netty creates new TLS contexts on each connection](https://github.com/unfiltered/unfiltered/issues/111)